# jQuery expandable input div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form with inputs are tasks with headers and its description. Is there any effective way in jQuery to make the details under header of each input able to toggle every time the header is clicked?

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="todo-task">

    <div class="task-header">Sample Header</div>

    <div class="task-date">25/06/2017</div>

    <div class="task-description">Description</div>

</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.task-header').click(clickFunction)

function clickFunction () {
  if ($('.task-description').is(":visible")) {
    $('.task-description').hide()
  } else {
    $('.task-description').show()
  } 
}
```

Functioning example: https://codepen.io/rp3/pen/yLOGgKB

---

If you wanted a solution for multiple headers & descriptions, data attributes might be the way to go. Add data attributes to the html you posted:

```
<div class="todo-task" data-headergroup="1">
  <div class="task-header" data-headergroup="1">Sample Header</div>
  <div class="task-date" data-headergroup="1">25/06/2017</div>
  <div class="task-description" style="display: none" data-headergroup="1">Description</div>
</div>
```

Then the js would be something more like this:

```
$('.task-header').click(clickFunction)

function clickFunction () {
  let headerGroupNumber = this.getAttribute('data-headergroup')
  if ($('.task-description').is(":visible")) {
    $(".task-description[data-headergroup='" + headerGroupNumber +"']").hide()
  } else {
     $(".task-description[data-headergroup='" + headerGroupNumber +"']").show()
  } 
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/rp3/pen/BaKvpOv

Comment: My apologies I did not explain it clearly. Here's the code I'm working on. [link](https://codepen.io/Yuzz3010/pen/xxVmqOp). For each input I want its description and date to toggle..

Comment: @p_w_hh You should still be able to implement that second answer - just add `$(".task-date[data-headergroup='" + headerGroupNumber +"']").hide()` into the same `if` block with `$(".task-description[data-headergroup='" + headerGroupNumber +"']").hide()`, and the same for the `.show()` block. I edited  https://codepen.io/rp3/pen/BaKvpOv to show that a little more clearly.

Comment: Problem is, it only works for the Sample Header. If I create a new task it won't function. And I want the details to be hiden only if header is clicked, so it shouldn't be display:"none" from the beginning?

Comment: Sure - then you can remove the `display: none`. The toggle functions will still work. 

As for the new tasks that you're creating, you'd need to have each task that is dynamically created have a unique value for the `data-headergroup` value. Same principle which you are applying there with your dynamic creation of taskId: `taskId: "task-"`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.toggle()` function of jquery to show and hide details when the header is clicked.

Here I have wrapped your `details` with a new div with `id="taskDetails"` and when the header with `id="taskHeader"` is clicked it will toogle the details.

for further adding the toogle option you can refer https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```js
$("#taskHeader").click(function() {
  $("#taskDetails").toggle();
});
```

```css
.task-header {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="todo-task">

  <div id="taskHeader" class="task-header">

    Sample Header

  </div>

  <div id="taskDetails">

    <div class="task-date">25/06/2017</div>

    <div class="task-description">Description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated:**

If you have multiple divs with `todo-task` you can do by following:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document.body).on("click", "div.task-header", function() {
    $(this).nextAll().toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.task-header {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.todo-task {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="todo-task">

  <div class="task-header">Sample Header</div>

  <div class="task-date">25/06/2017</div>

  <div class="task-description">Description</div>

</div>

<div class="todo-task">

  <div class="task-header">Sample Header</div>

  <div class="task-date">25/06/2017</div>

  <div class="task-description">Description</div>


</div>
```

Comment: My apologies I did not explain it clearly. Here's the code I'm working on: https://codepen.io/Yuzz3010/pen/xxVmqOp. For each input I want its description and date to toggle..

Comment: see my updated code. that will work for your use case.

Comment: It does indeed! Thank you so much!